# How can I limit a list based on a custom date field

Tags: date, custom-field

I a trying to display a simple event listing. I set up a custom date field called eventDate to note when the event happens.

This code delivers me the list of events sorted by eventDate:

```
 {% for event in craft.entries.find({section: 'events', order: 'eventDate'}) %}
    <a class="eventSummary" href="{{ event.url }}">
        <span class="date">{{ event.eventDate }}</span>
        <span class="eventTitle">{{ event.title }}</span>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

However, I want to omit events whose eventDate falls before the current date/time. If it were an entry date I guess I'd just use "after", but I am not sure how to apply that to a custom date field.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `.after` would work, but I've used this way:

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').limit(null) %}

{% for entry in entries.eventDate('>=' ~ (now.date)).order('eventDate DESC') %}
    {# Show entry #}  
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually you should be able to specify your custom field as part of the chained element criteria:

```
{% set currentAndFutureEvents = craft.entries.section('events').eventDate('>= ' ~ now).order('eventDate DESC') %}
```

Source: https://plus.google.com/111247306448293182882/posts/Uu6ZuTH1NBu